# Are there any exceptions to not wearing tallit on Tish'a B'Av morning?

Tags: minhag, tallit-gadol, tisha-bav

In Minhag Ashkenaz, people do not wear the *tallit gadol* for Tish'a B'av Shacharit. I don't recall if this is a universal rule that applies to everyone, or if it is OK for those involved with certain parts of *tefillah* to do so.

For example, does the shat'z wear it? Do the Torah reader and those receiving *aliyot* wear it? I thought, perhaps there is an exception for "kavod" or similar reasons.

Comment: Perhaps in the case where the person will not have the opportunity to don a tallit gadol later.

Comment: In the Ashkenaz shuls that I attended, not wearing the tallis gadol for Tish'a B'av Shacharit, was a universal custom that applied to everyone, including the shat"z, ba'al korei etc.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Arizal actually wore tallit and tefillin by Shacharit.

Comment: @ezra - See the Be'er Heitev in סימן תקנה  that says: תפילין. מהר''ם גאלנט''י היה מניח' בביתו והיה קורא ק''ש ואח''כ היה הולך לבית הכנסת כ''כ בהלק''ט ח''ב סימן קל''ט וכתב שכן מצא כתוב להאר''י ז''ל - so it seems he didn't do it in public.

Comment: @ezra the question was about Minhag Ashkenaz